# How to read an excel file with polars without header?

Tags: python-polars

I want to read an excel file without setting a header in polars. When i use `df = pl.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name = 0)` i receive a dataframe with selected column names. But I won't use the first row as header. I need to drop the first 3 rows and then set the top row as the header of the dataframe.  How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried setting`has_header` in the [`read_csv_options`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_excel.html#polars-read-excel)

Comment: ```df = pl.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name=0, read_csv_options={"has_header": False,})``` This worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help to ignore the header of the excel file.

```
df = pl.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name=0, read_csv_options={"has_header": False})
```